# How do I run the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to see verbose output for the build

Tags: azure-pipelines, verbosity, dotnetcorecli

I know there are outright `verbosityRestore` and `verbosityPack` inputs.. but what about for the regular 'build' of a .csproj file?

I've tried to find the answer in the documentation. I'm a bit frustrated, as I think I should know this

Ultimately, how do I achieve the equivalent of this MSBuild option: `-verbosity:level` as [documented in the MSBuild command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022), through the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task?

My project file is in SDK format, if it means anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came across [this microsoft piece](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild) that connected the dots for me. I was so close.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.vbproj'
    arguments: '-verbosity:diag'
```

> The dotnet msbuild command allows access to a fully functional
> MSBuild.
>
> The command has the exact same capabilities as the existing MSBuild
> command-line client for SDK-style projects only. The options are all
> the same. For more information about the available options, see the
> MSBuild command-line reference.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue. You  can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). This will help other users who has the same issue .